# No response from menu option buttons

Tags: java, android

menu buttons are not responding in this code . But the same code with another activity works correctly and gave responses.Update.java code works correctly.Cant identify what the problem is..

ItemAdd.java

```
   public class ItemAdd extends AppCompatActivity implements   View.OnClickListener {


  @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_add);



    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    //toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_menu_slideshow);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

      toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_slidesho w));

    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intenthome = new Intent(ItemAdd.this,     MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intenthome);

        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    if(id == R.id.account) {
        Intent intentaccount = new Intent(ItemAdd.this, account.class);
        startActivity(intentaccount);

    }

    if(id==R.id.action_notify) {
        Intent intentNotify = new Intent(ItemAdd.this, Notification.class);
        startActivity(intentNotify);

    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

  }
```

Update.java`

```
public class Update extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_update);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    //toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_menu_slideshow);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_slideshow));

    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intenthome = new Intent(Update.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intenthome);

        }
    });



}
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    if(id == R.id.account) {
        Intent intentaccount = new Intent(Update.this, account.class);
        startActivity(intentaccount);

    }

    if(id==R.id.action_notify) {
        Intent intentNotify = new Intent(Update.this, Notification.class);
        startActivity(intentNotify);

    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

Menu

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <item
      android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_Help"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
  <item
     android:id="@+id/action_notify"
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_white_24dp"
     android:title="action_favorite"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
  <item
     android:id="@+id/account"
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_account_circle_white_24dp"
     android:title="action_favorite"
     app:showAsAction="always"/>
  <item android:id="@+id/search"
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
     android:title="item_search"
     app:showAsAction="always"/>
 </menu>
```

Comment: please post `menu main xml`

Comment: but it is working in all activities except this..

Comment: toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_slidesho w)); You have a spacing here. Is it from pasting the code here or this is actually how it looks like in your code?

Comment: actually space is there, it is a mistake when i paste here.